# Converting a matrix loop into an equivalent function

Tags: matlab

Given a recursive loop similar to the following:

```
  A = [5,2;0,2]
  B = [5;6]
  x = [0;7]

  for i = 1:10
   x(:,i+1) = A * x(:,i) + B
  end
```

How can this represented without a loop?

Sample output:

```
[ 0, 19, 140, 797, 4186, 21339, 107520, 539257, 2699606, 13504679, 67536700;
  7, 20,  46,  98,  202,   410,    826,   1658,    3322,     6650,    13360]
```

Comment: The fastest way to compute this kind of "double sequence" will be to mathematically (pencil + paper) solve the sequence. So for example the nth term of the second sequence (7,20,46...) can be directly obtained with `13*2^(n-1)-6`. The first sequence  is a bit harder to calculate but can also be solved.

Comment: If you want to speed up your code, [preallocate the output array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html), and end your statements with a semicolon. Avoiding loops is something that was important in MATLAB 20 years ago, but today is not nearly as important. MATLAB uses "Just in Time Compilation" (JIT) to significantly speed up code (100x) compared to the old interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking to create a recursive function. If so, the below might work for you.

```
A = [5,2;0,2]
B = [5;6]
x = [0;7]

x = myRecursive(A,B,x, 10)

function [x] = myRecursive(A,B,x,n)
        x(:,end+1) = A * x(:,end) + B;  
    if size(x,2) <= n
        x = myRecursive(A,B,x,n);
    end
end
```

Comment: Like your answer, +1! Maybe you can try `x(:,end+1) = A * x(:,end) + B;` instead in `myRecursive` for speeding up a bit.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your comment. Good catch although I didn't get a significant change in performance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more mathy approach by solving the general formula for your recursion

```
u = pinv(A-eye(2))*B;
C = arrayfun(@(n) A^n*(x+u)-u,0:10,'UniformOutput',false);
M = cat(2,C{:});
```

which gives

```
M =

 Columns 1 through 9:

          0         19        140        797       4186      21339     107520     539257    2699606
          7         20         46         98        202        410        826       1658       3322

 Columns 10 and 11:

   13504679   67536700
       6650      13306
```

Comment: out of curiosity, I did a quick time test on the for loop provided by the questioner, my solution (recursive function) and yours. I was surprised that your solution took more processor time than my recursive function. (I guess I'll stick with the for loop which was fastest of all.

Comment: @greengrass62 Thanks for your comments. Yes, my solution is absolutely the slowest one without any surprise since matrix power `A^n` is a super expensive operation, which has to compute `n` times matrix multiplication for given `n`. Also `arrayfun` is actually another form of `for` loop. I also suggest using `for` loop or the recursion as you answered.

Comment: `arrayfun` is just a way to hide a loop. But you're calling an anonymous function in every loop iteration, instead of some simple arithmetic, and so the JIT has a lot more trouble to optimize it. This is why this solution is slow. An explicit loop that doesn't call any functions will always be faster, unfortunately.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for your explanation. I have to admit that my approach is mathy but inefficient for programming. From the complexity perspective, mine is `O(n^2)` while the `for` loop and the answer with recursive method are both `O(n)`. I would say mine just provides the math thinking but not that practical.